# Created view across different database and fetch column and some fields in database

Tags: mysql

If I have database test1 and database test2, and table employee1 under database test1 and table employee2 under database test2, is it possible to create a view of employee2 under database test1 in MySQL. If so, can you show me the syntax.?
and i want to also fetch some column and columns in in test2 tables is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

CREATE VIEW test1.emp2_view as select * from test2.employee2;